# Pyramid: how to set SCRIPT_NAME in request.environ

Tags: python, nginx, environment-variables, pyramid, wsgi

I have a Pyramid app proxied behind nginx for which I'm trying to set `SCRIPT_NAME` in `request.environ`.

I've tried:

- exporting it in the shell `pserve` is running in
- exporting it in the shell `nginx` is running in
- defining it in the Pyramid configuration file
- manually setting it on `gevent.wsgi.WSGIServer.environ` before `serve_forever()`

Non-standard values I define in the last step are available, but `SCRIPT_NAME` is always empty, which seems to indicate it's being overwritten from somewhere else.

How can I set it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at repoze.vhm.

It usually solves all my virtual hosting problems. (subpath, virtual root etc...). Biggest advantage of repoze.vhm is, that your pyramid app can stay completely unaware of the external url und path. You do have to be careful though, that you use request.route_url and other methods when generating urls for your site/app (but that should be good practice anyway).

https://github.com/repoze/repoze.vhm

Answer (score 0):

`SCRIPT_NAME` is set by the WSGI server on a per-request basis. If your server doesn't have a hook to set it (waitress has a `url_prefix=...` setting) then you can easily just add a middleware at the stop of your middleware stack that sets it for you. Instead of writing your own custom middleware you can also use the paste prefix middleware which will allow you to append to the `SCRIPT_NAME`. It also supports overriding `wsgi.url_scheme` via translating the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header which will help with https.

The best way to use the middleware is by adding it to your ini file. There are some good examples here in the waitress documentation. I will replicate one below just to be more clear. [1]

```
[app:myapp]
use = egg:mypackage#myapp

[filter:paste_prefix]
use = egg:PasteDeploy#prefix

[pipeline:main]
pipeline =
    paste_prefix
    myapp

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
listen = 127.0.0.1:8080
```

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/#using-behind-a-reverse-proxy