# Load a Pyramid App with Gunicorn in a different path than /

Tags: gunicorn, pyramid

I have a Pyramid application that I am loading with Gunicorn. My ini file has the following:

```
[app:main]
use = egg:my_example
...
[server:main]
use = egg:gunicorn
host = localhost
port = 5900
workers = 1
worker_class = gevent
```

I start Gunicorn witn:

```
gunicorn --paste ./development.ini
```

So my application is available at http://127.0.0.1:5900

What do I need to to do so my application is available in other path rather than / ,for example at http://127.0.0.1:5900/**my_example**

I saw the following posts:
[pyramid pserve in different root path than /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502411/pyramid-pserve-in-different-root-path-than)
and [Pyramid: how to set SCRIPT_NAME in request.environ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710197/pyramid-how-to-set-script-name-in-request-environ/43245748) but I'm still not able to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rutter is the right answer if you want all the incoming urls to just remove the prefix from them (for example, `http://127.0.0.1:5900/my_example/foo/bar` navigates to the `/foo/bar` route in your app). This seems to be what you're describing and the ini snippet in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43506460/704327 should be sufficient. Rutter will also prepare the environment correctly so that your app will generate the correct urls with the `/my_example` prefix when using `request.route_path` and `request.route_url`.